# unexpected character after line continuation character. Also to keep rows after floating point rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset in which I want to keep row just after a floating value row and remove other rows.

For eg, a column of the dataframe looks like this:

```
17.3

Hi Hello

Pranjal

17.1

[aasd]How are you

I am fine[:"]

Live Free
```

So in this I want to preserve:

```
Hi Hello

[aasd]How are you
```

and remove the rest. I tried it with the following code, but an error showed up saying "unexpected character after line continuation character". Also I don't know if this code will solve my purpose

## Dropping extra rows

```
for ind in data.index:
    if re.search((([1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?, ind):
        ind+=1
    else:
        data.drop(ind)
```

Comment: Try [`\d+\.\d+\s*(.*\s*)(?:(?!\d+\.\d+)[\s\S])*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZKBbAY/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex has to be a string, you can't just write it like that.

```
re.search((('[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?', ind):
```

edit - but actually i think the rest of your code is wrong too.

what you really want is something more like this:

```
import pandas as pd


l = ['17.3',
     'Hi Hello',
     'Pranjal',
     '17.1',
     '[aasd]How are you',
     'I am fine[:"]',
     'Live Free']

data = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['col'])

data[data.col.str.match('\d+\.\d*').shift(1) == True]
```

logic:

if you have a dataframe with a column that is all string type (won't work for mixed type decimal and string you can find the decimal / int entries with the regex '\d+.?\d*'. If you shift this mask by one it gives you the entries *after* the matches. use that to select the rows you want in your dataframe.

Comment: Yup its showing ```invalid syntax```. How to resolve it?

Comment: hard to say, i'm not sure exactly what you're doing. I'm adding some code that works though, so hopefully you can adapt that to your needs.

Comment: The issue got solved, actually in this ```re.search((('[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)|(\.[0-9]+))([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?', ind):``` the regular expression contains the two starting brackets also.